# Receive some notification from Postgres server that it is about to shut down

Tags: postgresql

We have a replication setup of total 2 Postgres servers. (Synchronous physical replication)
One is the primary and other is the replica which is in standby mode (readonly).
If the replica system/Postgres crashes(gracefully or forcefully) we want the replication setup to work as asynchronous mode instead of synchronous.

To achieve this we want to receive some trigger/notification from the replica Postgres server right before it shuts down, so that we can change our replication mode to asynchronous.

We cannot make this change after the replica crashes because in that case there is a small window of time where the replication is synchronous and replica is down and any transactions wont commit on the primary.

Is there any way to receive some notification from the replica Postgres server right before it is about to shut down? (for a system crash or Postgres crash)

Comment: No. In addition, it is in the nature of a crash that the system normally doesn't know in advance.